# WCF Service along With LINQ to SQL in asp.net

Tags: linq, wcf

I have Created the WCF Service in my application which involves LINQ Concepts but i cant understand how to call that service to my web pages.Can anyone say me how to call the service that i have created to my application with the detailed steps along with some sample codings So that i can proceed further? Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Do you want to call the service from code behind class or from browser (AJAX)? Where do you host the service?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample I put together to show how to call a WCF RESTful service that returns the result from LINQ from a basic web page using jQuery's `$.ajax` function.  Whether you're returning from a LINQ to objects or LINQ to SQL, the basic concept should be the same -- I'm using a basic LINQ-to-object just to illustrate the point.

---

Here's the WCF Service (**Service2.svc.cs**):

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service2
{
    public static List<string> myValues = new List<string>()
    {
        "Apple", "Orange", "Apricot", "Banana", "Grape", "Peach", "Plum"
    };

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate="Filter?q={filter}", 
        ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public IEnumerable<string> FilterList(string filter)
    {
        var items = from v in myValues
                    where v.StartsWith(filter)
                    select v;

        return items;
    }
```

This is a simple service that uses LINQ to return only those elements in my `List<string>` that start with the letter passed in.  So if you pass in 'P', you get "Peach" and "Plum" returned as an `IEnumerable<string>`.

This service is set up to return data from a GET request because of the use of the `WebGet` attribute.  This indicates that this method can only be called via an HTTP GET request.  The service method is set up to return data in JSON format (which is more stream-lined than XML, but not as extensible).  It's set up that way because of the `ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json` setting for the `WebGet` attribute.

When I invoke this method from my application (or a browser!) and pass in the letter "P" for my filter parameter, my response to the client is this (via Fiddler):

`["Peach","Plum"]`

This is a simple JSON-notated array that's returned.  I can then use this returned data to do whatever.

Also notice that I didn't have to convert the `IEnumberable<string>` to JSON format -- WCF's built-in JSON serializer did that for me.

**EDIT:** You can replace my simple LINQ-to-objects with a LINQ-to-SQL query and it will work with everything else unchanged:

```
public IEnumerable<string> FilterList(string filter)
{
    DbTest1DataContext context = new DbTest1DataContext();
    var names = from n in context.Attendees
                where n.Name.StartsWith(filter)
                select n.Name;

    return names;
}
```

My `DbTest1DataContext` is my LINQ-to-SQL context pointing to a database that has an Attendees table with a column of Name.  Everything else in this answer remains unchanged (web.config, HTML, jQuery, etc.).

---

Here's my web.config for the service (**web.config**):

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfRestService1.Service2AspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfRestService1.Service2">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WcfRestService1.Service2AspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfRestService1.Service2" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This is pretty much standard, out-of-the-box configuration except for the endpoint behavior, which I've set to use `webHttp`.

---

Here's my client code (**TestService.htm**):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#sendit").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Service2.svc/Filter",
                    data: { q: $("#source").val() },
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var theResults = $("#results");
                        theResults.empty();
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            theResults.append("<li>" + item + "</li>");
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (x, t, m) { alert(t + " :: " + m); }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Starts with: <input id="source" type="text" />
            <button id="sendit">Send It</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul id="results">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a very simple page that takes the input from a text box (id = source) and, after you click on the button (id = sendit), it invokes my WCF RESTful service.  I'm using jQuery for this, but you can see that I'm passing my filter value in the data property of the `$.ajax` call ( `data: { q: $("#source").val() }` ), I'm setting this up as a GET request (`type: "GET"`), because that's how I've configured the service.  The data type that I expect to get back is JSON (`dataType: "json"`).  And if my service call is successful, I invoke my success handler, which then just adds the returned strings to a `<ul>` element.

Hopefully this gives you a good starting point for retrieving a set of values from a LINQ query and sending it to a web-based client.  Please let me know if there are more questions and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Hope this helps!